# Input Type Radio Event in ASP.Net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a table generated by code behind with input type Radio Button. It looks like this

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sbTable As New StringBuilder

    Dim btn As HtmlInputRadioButton = New HtmlInputRadioButton()
    btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "addLayer()")
    ' cell.Controls.Add(btn)


    sbTable.Append("<table border='1px solid black' id='myTable' runat='server'> ")
    sbTable.Append("<thead>")
    sbTable.Append("<tr>")
    sbTable.Append("<th >No.</th>")
    sbTable.Append("<th >Division</th>")
    sbTable.Append("<th >Show</th>")



    sbTable.Append("</thead>")
    sbTable.Append("<tbody>")



    sbTable.Append("<tr>")
    sbTable.Append("<td>1</td>")
    sbTable.Append("<td>A</td>")
    sbTable.Append("<td><input type='radio' name='Overall' runat='server' id='radioA' value='A'  OnServerChange='RadioButton_CheckedChanged' AutoPostBack='true'/></td>")
    sbTable.Append("</tr>")




    sbTable.Append("<tr>")
    sbTable.Append("<td>2</td>")
    sbTable.Append("<td>B</td>")
    sbTable.Append("<td><input type='radio' name='Overall' runat='server' id='radioB' value='B'  OnServerChange='RadioButton_CheckedChanged' AutoPostBack='true'/></td>")
    sbTable.Append("</tr>")



    sbTable.Append("</tbody>")
    sbTable.Append("</table>")




    phTrendUk.Controls.Add(New Literal() With {.Text = sbTable.ToString})




End Sub
```

I want have an event when I click the radio button it will change label value

```
   Protected Sub RadioButton_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    idlbl.Text = "Click"
End Sub
```

I already added RadioButton_CheckedChanged, but it didn't work. Can anyone help with this case?

Comment: ...why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Comment: ...and why are you generating HTML like that? Why aren't you putting it in the `.aspx`/`.ascx` file as _actual_ markup? Also, `runat="server"` does not work like that...

Comment: actually i have to generate table dynamically so I create code like that @Dai

Comment: Trust me when I say it's a _lot easier_ to render a `<table>`'s HTML markup in the `.aspx` file than horribly abusing a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: So is it possible to enable event when I use StringBuilder? @Dai

Comment: No; it is **not possible** to use WebForms server-side-events using your current approach.

Comment: any suggestion please? The Requirement is I have to generate data inside a table dynamically with radio button for each row. So when I click one of those radio button, It runs some function like generate table or etc @Dai

Comment: Have you ever used `<asp:Repeater>`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248720/discussion-between-kemiko-setiawan-and-dai).

Comment: I recommend you read these (vintage) articles from WebForms' heyday that discuss how to use dynamically-created controls in WebForms: https://web.archive.org/web/20110828071315/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082008-1.aspx https://web.archive.org/web/20110828195831/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx  https://web.archive.org/web/20110823031659/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082102-1.aspx https://web.archive.org/web/20110828200002/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx

Comment: See my sample below - it is dead easy - less work then just about any other platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can do this.

The question is much "where" does the list of options come from for the RadioButtonList?

Also, you don't need a table, nor do  you need all that code to generate the markup. Just drag + drop in a Radiobutton list onto your web form from the toolbox.

You now have this:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">

        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And in form view, then use this:

[image]

So, we now can edit/add items using the designer.

So, we add 1, and text of Division

And 2 for overall,

So, this:

[image]

Now, of course the above creates this markup:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Division</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Overall</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

So, we have autopostback=true, and the above 2 choices.

So, property sheet, and then event tab, and double click on the SelectedIndexChanged event, from here:

[image]

Now, we can write code to say set the value of the label we have below.

```
Protected Sub RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim strResult As String = ""

    If RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        strResult = "No selection made"
    Else
        strResult = "Value selected = " & RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value &
                    " Text selected value = " & RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text
    End If

    Label1.Text = strResult


End Sub
```

Also, we can set the buttons to go vertical, or horizontal.

And we can even add some styling to the buttons.

So, we now have this:

[image]

And you can certainly use code to fill out the list of choices.

Say like this:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
```

And on our page load, then this code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadButtonList
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadButtonList()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT  ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            RadioButtonList1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
            RadioButtonList1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Same code for selected index changed, and we get this:

[image]

So, use a radiobutton list.

And not only can you use the editor to add the list of choices, but the second example shows how we can even use a database to drive the choices.

Note that each choice has a display text value, and then a hidden choice value, and I suppose the index of the choice also could be used.

And in code behind, you can freely use code to add choices if you don't want to hard code the markup, or as per second example, pull the choices from a database.

Or, maybe from code, you want choice 1 to 5.

So, then this:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And then say this code on load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        For i = 1 To 5
            Dim OneChoice As New ListItem("Choice " & i, i)
            RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(OneChoice)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

And now we have this:

[image]

So you can use the built-in items editor, you can feed the RB list data, or you can even simply loop and add choices in code.